# secant method in Python to solve f(x) = 0

Tags: python, math, methods

How can I use the secant method in Python to solve the equation f(x) = 0 given 2 intial guesses, x0 and x1?.

```
def secant(f,x0,x1,tol):
```

I need to use it to find solutions to quadratics and higher factors of x, for example, x^3 -4x^2 + 1 = 0 for a given interval.
This is just a shot in the dark so any links to useful websites will also be appreciated!

Comment: please show what you have tried yet, stack overflow is not a code making machine.

Comment: Ever heard of Newton's method? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1uN8cBGVpfs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 9):

Wikipedia has a [quick overview of secant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method#The_method) which looks like

[image]

Translating the first iteration into Python looks something like

```
x2 = (x0 * f(x1) - x1 * f(x0)) / (f(x1) - f(x0))
```

Instead of calling `f(x0)` and `f(x1)` multiple times, we should call them once and store the value:

```
fx0 = f(x0)
fx1 = f(x1)
x2 = (x0 * fx1 - x1 * fx0) / (fx1 - fx0)
```

For the second iteration we have to calculate

```
x3 = (x1 * fx2 - x2 * fx1) / (fx2 - fx1)
```

but we don't want to have to re-write the equation with new variables every time. Instead, we shift the values along: let `x1` take the value of `x2`, `x2` take the value of `x3`, and so on. We can do this repeatedly in a loop like

```
# store initial values
fx0 = f(x0)
fx1 = f(x1)
while (something):
    # do calculation
    x2 = (x0 * fx1 - x1 * fx0) / (fx1 - fx0)
    # shift variables (prepare for next loop)
    x0,  x1  = x1,  x2
    fx0, fx1 = fx1, f(x2)
```

Now we just have to know when to stop, when the difference between our last answer and 0 is less than `tol`: `abs(f(x2) - 0) < tol`, which can be simplified to `abs(fx1) < tol`.

So the function looks like

```
def secant(f, x0, x1, tol):
    # store initial values
    fx0 = f(x0)
    fx1 = f(x1)
    while abs(fx1) < tol:
        # do calculation
        x2 = (x0 * fx1 - x1 * fx0) / (fx1 - fx0)
        # shift variables (prepare for next loop)
        x0,  x1  = x1,  x2
        fx0, fx1 = fx1, f(x2)
    return x1
```

Now we only have one problem remaining: what happens if the loop never ends? Secant method is not guaranteed to converge to a solution. We need a way to stop the function if it runs too many times.

If we change the `while` loop to a `for` loop, it is guaranteed to stop after a set number of times. If we find an answer before that, we can quit early; otherwise we raise an error to let the user know it has not converged. The final function looks like

```
def secant(f, x0, x1, tol, max_iterations=100):
    # keep initial values for error reporting
    init_x0 = x0
    init_x1 = x1

    # store y values instead of recomputing them
    fx0 = f(x0)
    fx1 = f(x1)

    # iterate up to maximum number of times
    for _ in range(max_iterations):
        # see whether the answer has converged
        if abs(fx1) < tol:
            return x1

        # do calculation
        x2 = (x0 * fx1 - x1 * fx0) / (fx1 - fx0)
        # shift variables (prepare for next loop)

        x0,  x1  = x1,  x2
        fx0, fx1 = fx1, f(x2)

    # for loop has ended - failed to converge
    raise ValueError(
        "call to secant(f={}, x0={}, x1={}, tol={}," \
        " max_iterations={}) has failed to converge"
        .format(
            f.__name__,
            init_x0,
            init_x1,
            tol,
            max_iterations
        )
    )
```